# how to solve system.data.datarowview in vb.net using mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I want to display my data from a MySql database into DropDownList. This is the source code of my vb.net's program:

```vb
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim myConnection As MySqlConnection
    Dim myCommand As MySqlCommand
    Dim myDataAdapter As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim myDataSet As DataSet

    'Dim dt As New DataTable

    myConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; Database=latihan_ws; User ID=root;Password=;")
    myCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select id_or from olahraga", myConnection)

    myDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand)

    myDataSet = New DataSet()

    'myDataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("table", "olahraga")

    myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet)

    DropDownList1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)

    DropDownList1.DataBind()

    'InisialisasiDropDown()
End Sub
```

And finally i've got an error in DropDownList, that's

[image: DropDownList]

If you know the solution for my code, please write them on as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to set the DataTextField property to the name of the column that you want to display

```
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "id_or";
```

but probably you want this id to be the DataValueField and use a different (to be loaded) field for the description visible to your user

Comment: hehehe sorry, maybe i forgot to set property name. And now, it has been solved. thank you^^

Comment: Can I ask again Steve?

Comment: 'use the relation table
        myCommand = New MySqlCommand("Select atlet.id_or as 'idor', olahraga.nama_or as 'nama_olahraga' from olahraga, atlet where atlet.id_or=olahraga.id_or", myConnection)

        myDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand)

        myDataSet = New DataSet()

        myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet)

        'what is the column that i should fill, below:
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "id_or"

        DropDownList1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables(0)

        DropDownList1.DataBind()

Comment: Well, suppose _id_or_ is a number (the primary key of the table) while _name_olahraga_ is a just a descriptive text. Then you set _DataTextField = "name_olahraga"_ and _DataValueField = "id_or"_. So when you read the ddl _SelectedValue_ you get the _id_or_ while your user sees and chooses the descriptive text.

Comment: of course, i have tried it. then i Insert data and it successed . But the id that has inputed to the athlete's table remains the top id, even though i've chosen with a different value

Comment: Not clear for me what's happening on your side. I suggest to post a new question with all the details needed to understand the situation. In this way more people will look at your problem and you will have a better chance to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
DropDownList1.Items.Clear()

For Each row As DataRow In myDataSet.Tables(0).Rows
    DropDownList1.items.Add(row("Detail"))
Next row
```